# DatePickerDialog doesn't adjust itself to screen size correctly

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have a question about DatePickerDialog. I'm working on a really small screen. All of the other parts of the application are displayed properly, except DatePickerDialog. I'm generating it programmatically with the following code:

```
tmpYear = year;
tmpMonthOfYear = monthOfYear;
tmpDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dialogDateSetListener,
    tmpYear, tmpMonthOfYear, tmpDayOfMonth);
dialog.show();
```

Anyway, everything compiles, however, the result, when displayed, looks like this:

[image]

It looks like the year part is cut due to the size of the DatePicker. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: post you dailog xml code

Comment: @SohailZahid He has used DatePickerDialog not anything custom so that we don't need xml. Is it ??

Comment: I think this is a old emulator, not a real device.

Comment: Yes, this is an emulator with small resolution. There's no xml since I load everything programatically, i.e. with the code given above.

Answer (score 0):

To customize it, you should better use layout for the same.This will help to adjust according to the screen you want.

```
 <DatePicker
          android:id="@+id/date_pickerdialog"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:scaleX="0.60"
          android:scaleY="0.60"
          android:layout_marginLeft="-50dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to inflate this DatePicker into a DatePickerDialog object?

Comment: From the xml, I mean.

Comment: Using this layout didn't work either, I saved it in the file datepicker.xml in layout folder, then used the following code:

`Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
  dialog.setContentView((DatePicker)((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.datepicker, null));

  dialog.show();`

And the result looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/c9bmr4)